# Elasticsearch boosting syntax PHP

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch

I did read the elasticsearch documentation but it lacks examples, for me.

I have put some documents in the es-engine, they contain the field "text" and "title".
Now I want to boost up the hits in the field "title". I'm using the php-api.

I tried this one:

```
 $params_ci['index'] = 'all';
 $params_ci['type'] = 'all';
 $params_ci['body']['query']['query_string']['query'] = $query;
 $params_ci['body']['function_score']['functions']['field_value_factor'] = array('field' => 'title',
                                                                                 'factor' => 1.2)
 $client = ElasticClientFactory::build();
 $client->search($params_ci)
```

But I get an error. Without the "function_score" it works.

```
 ... Parse Failure [No parser for element [function_score] ...
```

The biggest problem for me is how to translate the JSON in the documentation into the right place as arrays. I know JSON is like an array but often it fits not in my hierarchy of array?

Uses ElasticSearch Version: elasticsearch-1.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right synax is:

```
$params_ci['body']['query']['function_score']['functions']['field_value_factor'] = array('field' => 'title', 'factor' => 1.2)
```